# CSV and PyEnchant Python Program

Tags: python, csv

I'm attemping to comb through a list of a couple hundred thousand words in a csv file, in order to determine which ones are not english. I know I can utilize PyEnchant to do this, but I'm new to coding in general and could use some help on the details.

Here's what I have thus far, I've created a list "L" to print out all of the non-English words so that I can check them myself.

```
import enchant
import csv
L = []
with open('list.csv') as csvfile:
  shortcut = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=" ", quotechar="|")
  for row in shortcut:
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    if d is false:
        L.append(d)
print L
```

Can someone let me know where I've gone wrong here?

Comment: without being too familiar with pyenchant, the `if d is false` looks fishy; try capitalizing the `False` and use `==` instead of `is`, even better: `if not d:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you create instance of enchant, using check to check each word in your file
your code is reading each line of file, however it could contain more than one word each line, so please also iterate each row.

```
import enchant
import csv

with open('list.csv') as csvfile:
  shortcut = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=" ", quotechar="|")
  checker = enchant.Dict("en_US")
  l = [ word for row in shortcut for word in row if not checker.check(word) ]


print l
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!